# d3.js: Updating a pie with lables

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

I'm trying to set up a pie on d3.js that will constantly update its data (slices) and change the labels.
The slices of data may vary and are not constant (could be a 2 slices pie and 5 slices, etc.)

I've reviewed several of examples such as:

http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/VYud2/3/

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

But the thing is, my implementation is quite different since I use both text lables and paths.

The problem: data is not updated and text is not removed.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Kitt0s/vfkSs/

```
function tests (data) {
        data = data ? data : { "slice1": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1), "slice2": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1), "slice3": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1), "slice4": Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1) };
            var dataa = d3.entries(data);
            var cv_path = cv_svg.selectAll("g.slice")
                .data(cv_pie(dataa));

            cv_path.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "slice")
                .append("path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return cv_color(i); } ) 
                .attr("d", cv_arc)
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

            cv_path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", cv_arcTween);

            cv_path.exit().remove();

            var cv_text = d3.selectAll(".slice")
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    d.innerRadius = 0;
                    d.outerRadius = cv_r;
                    return "translate(" + cv_arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
                .attr("font-size", "30px")
                .text(function(d) { return d.data.key + "(" + d.data.value + ")"; });

                cv_text.exit().remove();
}
```

I've spent an awful lot of time trying to get this right, but still seem to get stuck (every time something else breaks.. :P)
Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. The key is to treat the text exactly the same as the paths and handle the `.exit()` selection by removing it. I've modified your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vfkSs/1/). I've removed the `g` elements to make it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess the    g  element was confusing me.. It works great! one thing though, the text wasn't updating, so what I did was taken the text update function out side of the .enter() function. Here is the final one: http://jsfiddle.net/vfkSs/2/ Thanks again!